# Actualizar un access con la información de un excel desde otro access usando VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Creo que el titulo lo dice todo, pero lo expongo aquí nuevamente.

Tengo un Access que utilizo con macros para controlar distintos access. En un momento dado necesito actualizar la información de una tabla de otro access con la información contenida en un excel usando vba.

He intentado varias opciones de vba pero me da muchos errores diferentes

¿tiene alguien algún metodo o similar que pueda ayudarme en esta tarea?

Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofú, por fin lo he conseguido. He tardado horas pero ya lo tengo. Por si alguien (o yo mismo) tiene esta duda en el future, esto se hace así.

```
Option Compare Database

Sub InsertarExcelEnTablaExterna()

Ruta = "C:\Nueva carpeta"
ExcelOrigen = "Libro1.xlsx"
AccessDestino = "Base de datos2.accdb"
PestañaOrigen = "Sheet1"
TablaDestino = "Tabla1"

RutaExcel = Ruta & "\" & ExcelOrigen
RutaAccess = Ruta & "\" & AccessDestino

Dim ExcelConn As ADODB.Connection

Dim SQL_Excel As String

    Set ExcelConn = New ADODB.Connection
    ExcelConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
                   "Data Source=" & RutaExcel & "; " & _
                   "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"

    SQL_Excel = "INSERT INTO [" & TablaDestino & "] In '" & RutaAccess & "' SELECT * FROM [" & PestañaOrigen & "$]"
    ExcelConn.Execute (SQL_Excel)

ExcelConn.Close
Set RS_Excel = Nothing
Set ExcelConn = Nothing

End Sub
```