# Problemas con el TIPO de campo en consultas ADO con más de 8 RecordSet

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

[TITULO ORIGINAL: Problemas al hacer INSERT INTO con un campo MEMO en una consulta con 20 recordsets o más]

Estoy intentando añadir información de una tabla excel con un campo de texto muy largo, con muchos caracteres en una tabla con un campo MEMO.

El contenido del campo en el excel que estoy intentando meter en el Access es el siguiente:

_1_1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_2_1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_3_1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_4_1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_5_1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_6_1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_7_1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_8_1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_9_1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_10_1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

que tiene 391 caracteres,

El código ha sido sacado de una consulta que he hecho esta misma mañana:

```
Option Compare Database

Sub InsertarExcelEnTablaExterna()

Ruta = "C:\Nueva carpeta"
ExcelOrigen = "Libro1.xlsx"
AccessDestino = "Base de datos2.accdb"
PestañaOrigen = "Sheet2"
TablaDestino = "Tabla2"

RutaExcel = Ruta & "\" & ExcelOrigen
RutaAccess = Ruta & "\" & AccessDestino

Dim ExcelConn As ADODB.Connection

Dim SQL_Excel As String

    Set ExcelConn = New ADODB.Connection
    ExcelConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
                   "Data Source=" & RutaExcel & "; " & _
                   "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"

    SQL_Excel = "INSERT INTO [" & TablaDestino & "] In '" & RutaAccess & "' SELECT " & _
    "[" & PestañaOrigen & "$].[Fecha] AS [Fecha], " & _
    "[" & PestañaOrigen & "$].[Textito] AS [Textito], " & _
    "[" & PestañaOrigen & "$].[Id] AS [Id], " & _
    "[" & PestañaOrigen & "$].[Numerico] AS [Numerico] " & _
    "FROM [" & PestañaOrigen & "$]"
    ExcelConn.Execute (SQL_Excel)

ExcelConn.Close
Set ExcelConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

[Consulta adición INSERT INTO de un excel a otro access distinto al de trabajo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/248599/33814)

Hasta aquí todo bien. La macro importa la información completa y correctamente. El problema viene cuando los 10 o 12 o 20 primeros resultados de la query son más cortos de 255 caracteres para el campo MEMO. Entonces la consulta INSERT INTO trunca el valor MEMO para el resto de recordsets.

El caso es que al hacer la operación, el valor es truncado a 255 caracteres, pero yo necesito el campo completo.

Sabe alguien como solucionar este problema?

Imagen de la tabla origen:
[image: Tabla de ejemplo]
Se puede apreciar que hay más de 255 caracteres.

Sinembargo tras realizar la instrucción INSERT INTO, la última fila es truncada a 255 caractéres quedando de la siguiente forma:
[image: Tabla resultado]

Si todo lo anterior lo hago poniendo en el primer registro la cadena de texto de más de 255 caracteres, la instrucción INSERT INTO funciona perfectamente para todos los registros, pero si los primeros 5 ó 10 ó 20 recordsets (no he buscado la cantidad exacta) tienen cadenas de texto más pequeñas de 255, es como si el software 'autodetectara' que el campo no es de tipo TEXT(MEMO)[longitud 65.535] sino de tipo CHAR(TEXTO)[longitud 255] {... si, en Microsoft se han lucido con las traducciones al español de los tipos de caracter...} y es entonces cuando trunca las cadenas largas como en el ejemplo expuesto en las imágenes.

Necesito forzar de alguna forma a la instrucción INSERT INTO a que trate esa columna como TEXT(MEMO) independientemente de este ¿bug?

¿Sabe alguien como ayudarme?

---

REEDITO LA PREGUNTA para replantear el concepto que hay que resolver

Sigo estudiando este asunto. Despues de varias horas más y analizándolo poco a poco, veo que cuando se establece una conexión ADO a un Excel y se ejecuta una consulta SQL en un RecordSet, la herramienta solo extrae la información del origen y CALCULA el tipo que contendrá el resultado. Para ello utiliza los 8 primeros registros del resultado.
En el ejemplo siguiente he modificado la tabla de pruebas de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna B 'Textito' contiene cadenas de texto, pero en los 8 primeros registros hay numeros. Por lo tanto al ejecutar la sentencia SQL con la conexión ADO, la herramienta detectará que se trata de un campo numérico. Los registros posteriores tendrán el valor 'Null' porque no son números

La columna C es la famosa MEMO. Como no hay ningún RecordSet con más de 255 caracteres, será un simple 'VarChar' en lugar de un 'LongVarChar'

La columna D debería tener solo valores numéricos, pero como el campo está vacío para los 8 primeros registros, la consulta lo tratará como cadenas de texto

Así que la duda planteada en esta larga pregunta tiene que ser reformulada a ¿cómo se puede establecer que en una conexión ADO, el estudio automático del tipo de campos pueda ampliarse a TODOS los RecordSets en lugar de solo a los 8 primeros?

Comment: y cual es el tamaño del campo en la DB?

Comment: Es un campo de tipo MEMO. Sesentaypicomin caracteres

Comment: y la columna de excel es tipo texto?si es asi puedes cambiarla a general?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez Despues de testear más este problema te puedo asegurar que no depende del tipo de valor de la celda. He editado la pregunta para ampliar los detalles. La única solución que se me ocurre (nada elegante) es añadir al excel de origen una nueva primera fila con textos superiores a 255 caracteres en los campos MEMO de manera que la instrucción SQL interprete que efectivamente se trata de un campo MEMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porfin encuentro la solución. Al parecer este comportamiento es el que viene por defecto en las consultas a Excel. He seguido buscando hasta encontrar un tema similar en stackoverflow en ingles.

[Esto se soluciona editando el registro de Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46170343/reading-excel-sheet-using-ace-oledb-12-0-with-imex-1-not-working)

```
// En mi caso, con Office 2010 de 32 bits instalado en Windows de 64 bits
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel [TypeGuessRows] --> por defecto en 8, cambiar por el valor deseado
```